# I can't add border radius when I create a modelbottomsheet

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, border-radius, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

I've tried a lot of way to add border radius but they didn't work.

So this is the way I call bottom sheet

```
showModalBottomSheet(
                    isScrollControlled: true,
                    barrierColor: Color.fromARGB(92, 0, 0, 0),
                    backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                    context: context,
                    builder: (context) => DraggableScrollableSheet(
                      maxChildSize: 0.87,
                      initialChildSize: 0.87,
                      builder: ((context, scrollController) =>
                          PlaceMenuForDiscoverPage(),
                    ),
                  ),
```

And this is the main part of my bottom sheet

```
Container(
          color: const Color.fromARGB(0, 0, 0, 0),
          child: StreamBuilder(
              stream:
                  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Name').snapshots(),
              builder: (BuildContext context,
                  AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                return ListView(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  children: [
                    Positioned(
                        top: 0,
                        left: 0,
                        right: 0,
                        child: Stack(
                          children: [
                            SizedBox(
                              width: double.maxFinite,
                              height: 310,
                              child: PageView.builder(
                                  itemCount: 3,
                                  pageSnapping: true,
                                  itemBuilder: (context, pagePosition) {
                                    return Container(
                                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                                      child: Image.network(
                                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                          imgList[pagePosition], frameBuilder:
                                              (context, child, frame,
                                                  wasSynchronouslyLoaded) {
                                        return child;
                                      }, loadingBuilder: (context, child,
                                              loadingProgress) {
                                        if (loadingProgress == null) {
                                          return child;
                                        } else {
                                          return Center(
                                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                              color: Color.fromRGBO(
                                                  250, 17, 79, 1),
                                            ),
                                          );
                                        }
                                      }),
                                    );
                                  }),
                            ),
                          ],
                       )),
                    ],
                );
              })),
```

I've tried to add border radius to showmodalbottomsheet() part and my bottom sheet but they didn't work. Thanks for your help from now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `borderRadius` to Container inside `PlaceMenuForDiscoverPage` like blew, don't forget to add clipBehavior to container:

```
Container(
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,//<-- add this
        decoration: BoxDecoration(//<-- add this
          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: const Radius.circular(16.0),
              topRight: const Radius.circular(16.0)),
          color: const Color.fromARGB(0, 0, 0, 0),
        ),
        child: StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('Name')
                .snapshots(),
        ...
)
```

Comment: @Abdullah was it what you want?

Comment: @eamierho3ein it worked for picture but it didn't work for bottom sheet (I can still see white part of it). thx

Comment: @Abdullah could you show me the result of my answer? and point it out where is not ok?

Comment: @eamierho3ein of course! --> [Error](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/77537079/204152531-d10cf775-c21e-4202-8a59-05ced9a3c321.png)

Comment: are you using this container directly inside PlaceMenuForDiscoverPage or wrapping it with others widget? if you have some other widget as parent of this container could you add theme here?

Comment: I was using it under the scaffold but now I add container as parent of scaffold then I added theme there then problem solved.  Thanks for it. I really appreciated.

Comment: I assumed the container is a top level widget, glad to help.